# How would I make a custom keybind with a press of a button in Java?

Tags: java

As you may have read from the title, I am trying to make a custom keybind system in Java. Basically, I have a button (JButton), and what I want to happen is when a user clicks that button, it will wait for the user's input in order to set that as a keybind for future uses, but I have no idea how to do this. I've looked around the internet and found things that are somewhat similar, but implement a specific key input instead of any key input. If there is a question like this one already answered, please link me to it so I can check it out. To make it simple, I'll make a step-by-step list below. Basically:

1. Button is pressed (Done)
2. Programs waits for any keyboard input
3. Program reads the input
4. Program stops waiting for an input
5. Input is stored (either if that is KeyCode or something else that the input can be recognized by

If it can detect a combination of keys (like CTRL + SHIFT + T), then that is a pro. If it can detect extra keys (like macro keys or mouse buttons (ones on the side of the mouse), then that would be amazing too. Of course, those are other questions and I do not want to be asking more than one question at a time, but I will leave them here in case they are possible and someone knows/wants to implement them as well. Other than that, I really don't know how I would be able to achieve this. So far, the only thing that I have is just the mouse click function and nothing else. If you could help me, then that would be amazing. If you have any questions regarding my post, please ask them. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of a keypress editor.

[image: Keypress Editor]

When you press the Change Key button, then press a key on the keyboard, the displayed letter changes.

This requires more code to handle the Ctrl, Shift, or Alt keys, but this should be enough to get you started.

It's important that you extend and use the `KeyModel` class.  This model class is what makes the rest of the view and controller code possible.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class KeyPressEditor implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new KeyPressEditor());
    }

    private GetKey getKey;

    private KeyModel keyModel;

    private JButton button;

    private JTextField keyField;

    public KeyPressEditor() {
        this.getKey = new GetKey();
        this.keyModel = new KeyModel();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Key Press Editor");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Key to initiate function: ");
        panel.add(label);

        keyField = new JTextField(10);
        keyField.setEditable(false);
        keyField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        keyField.setText("K");
        panel.add(keyField);

        button = new JButton("Change Key");
        button.addActionListener(new ChangeKey());
        panel.add(button);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updateKeyField(String key) {
        keyField.setText(key);
    }

    public class ChangeKey implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            button.addKeyListener(getKey);
        }

    }

    public class GetKey extends KeyAdapter {        
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
            keyModel.addKeyEvent(event);
            char c = event.getKeyChar();
            String s = Character.toString(c).toUpperCase();
            updateKeyField(s);
            button.removeKeyListener(getKey);
        }
    }

    public class KeyModel {

        private List<KeyEvent> keyEvents;

        public KeyModel() {
            keyEvents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public List<KeyEvent> getKeyEvents() {
            return keyEvents;
        }

        public void addKeyEvent(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            this.keyEvents.add(keyEvent);
        }

    }
}
```