# JButton Key binding. Change the button text after clicking the button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keylistener

I have the simple GUI with 4 buttons (**b1, b2, b3, b4**) with icons and empty labels.
I would like to implement the following.:

If user clicks on **b1** and then clicks on any key on keyboard, mouse key (except Left and Right click) or mouse wheel, this key name should appear as button label over button icon.
Also if **b1** is already bound for example as "wheel down" and user wanna bind "wheel down" to **b2** too, **b1** label should become empty.
There shouldn't be two same text on two or more buttons.

All keyboard and mouse buttons should be available for setting them into buttons text (Esc, Tab, Capslock, Shift even ScrollLock and Pause)

Is it possible to implement it?

Here are the buttons with icons. I just added the expected example with red keys of how it should look before and after.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically you need to add an KeyListener to your Frame. And you track your pressed key in a variable until you press OK, heres a detailed documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: Here's a simple [keypress editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432577/how-would-i-make-a-custom-keybind-with-a-press-of-a-button-in-java/61434646#61434646) I whipped up for another question.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Unfortunately I'm new to swing, so it would be great to see some pseudocode for my case. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your buttons aren't wide enough to hold text like "scroll lock" or "caps lock".  What you're asking for can be done, but the code is not something that can be shown in a simple example.  I pointed you to a [keypress editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432577/how-would-i-make-a-custom-keybind-with-a-press-of-a-button-in-java/61434646#61434646) that I wrote that only handles keyboard letters.  Since you're new to Swing, I recommend the [Oracle Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).